# PHP PDO MSSQL stored procedures

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo

I have limited access to MSSQL database, I have CentOS server with PHP 5.6 and PDO library. I need need to run stored procedures that writes result to temporary table and after that make SELECT from that table to fetch required data.

IN FACT there are 3 statements - 2 of them execution of stored procedures and 1 SELECT. If I'm placing all of them to 1 statement - statement returns nothing (but should return at list 80 rows), however statement return no errors.

BUT if I divide statements - it returns error on second call.

```
General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [208] (severity 16) [(null)]
```

SO HERE IS CODE:`

```
try {
    $this->db = new PDO 
("dblib:host=".$options['host'].";dbname=".$options['db'], $options['user'], $options['pass'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true));
}catch (PDOException $e) {
  $this->addLog("Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage());
  return false;
}

$tmp = "##good123";
$hotelinctable = "##hotelinc123";

$sql = "EXEC sp_executesql @createtable = N'CREATE TABLE ".$hotelinctable." (inc int null)'

        EXEC sp_executesql N'EXEC up_prclm
        @CDateFrom = @CDFrom,
        @CDateTill = @CDTill,
        @DateFrom = @DFrom,
        @DateTill = @DTill,
        @ConfirmedDateFrom = @ConfDFrom,
        @ConfirmedDateTill = @ConfDTill,
        @PDateFrom = @PDFrom,
        @PDateTill = @PDTill,
        @Owner = @Own,
        @HPartner = @HPartn,
        @state = @StateInc,
        @TourList = @TList,
        @PartnerList = @PList,
        @PGroupList = @PGList,
        @MediatorList = @MList,
        @Curr = @CurrInc,
        @BaseCurr = @BaseCurrInc,
        @DateRate = @RateDate,
        @Rate = @RateType,
        @Round = @RoundType,
        @StatusList = @ClaimStatusList,
        @Name = @ResultTableName,
        @hotelinc = @HIncTableName,
        @TourCurrency = @TourCurrencyInc,
        @claimstr = @ClaimList',
        N'@CDFrom datetime2,@CDTill datetime2,@DFrom datetime2,@DTill datetime2,@ConfDFrom datetime2,@ConfDTill datetime2,@PDFrom datetime2,@PDTill datetime2,@Own int,@HPartn int,@StateInc int,@TList varchar(8000),@PList varchar(8000),@PGList varchar(8000),@MList varchar(8000),@CurrInc int,@BaseCurrInc int,@RateDate datetime2,@RateType int,@RoundType int,@ClaimStatusList varchar(8000),@ResultTableName varchar(8000),@HIncTableName varchar(8000),@TourCurrencyInc bit,@ClaimList varchar(8000)',
        '1900-01-01 00:00:00','2079-06-06 00:00:00','2017-05-12 00:00:00','2017-05-12 00:00:00','1900-01-01 00:00:00','2079-06-06 00:00:00','1900-01-01 00:00:00','2079-06-06 00:00:00',-2147483647,-2147483647,0,'','2870','','',2,1,'2017-05-12 00:00:00',0,0,'1, 2, 4, 5','".$tmp."','".$hotelinctable."',0,''
";



$r = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$r->execute();

$err = $r->errorInfo();
$this->addLog("ERRCHK: ".var_export($err, true));

$sql = "SELECT prclm.claim AS order_id, 
               prclm.amount AS full_cost, 
               prclm.net AS net_cost, 
               currency.alias AS currency, 
               prclm.hnet AS hotel_net, 
               prclm.fnet AS flights_net, 
               prclm.inet AS insurance_net, 
               prclm.tnet AS transfers_net, 
               prclm.enet AS excursions_net, 
               prclm.vnet AS visas_net, 
               prclm.supnet AS suppliment_net, 
               prclm.snet AS services_ner, 
               hpartner.name AS hotel_partner, 
               claim.confirmed AS is_confirmed
          FROM ".$tmp." prclm 
    INNER JOIN claim ON prclm.claim = claim.inc 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN order ord ON ord.inc = prclm.order 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN partner hpartner ON hpartner.inc = ord.partner 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN currency on currency.inc = prclm.currency
      ORDER BY prclm.inc DESC";

$r = $this->db->prepare($sql);
$r->execute();
$err = $r->errorInfo();
$this->addLog("ERRCHK: ".var_export($err, true));

$res = $r->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$this->addLog("RES: ".var_export($res, true));  `
```

Please advise - what is wrong, and how to call multiple procedures and then SELECT.